# "Backbone.Model.extend() is not a function", what have I done wrong?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am having a crack at Backbone and decided to open a jsFiddle to play around.

Unfortunately, I keep getting this error being thrown:

> Backbone.Model.extend is not a function

My code:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend();
```

I got this piece of code from a [Backbone tutorial](http://www.plexical.com/blog/2010/11/18/backbone-js-tutorial/).

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AFmQ2/).

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to include [`underscore.js`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) before `backbone.js` as in this updated version of your fiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AFmQ2/1/

From the [fine manual](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/):

> Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even see a reference to `underscore.js`. Thanks Mu!

Comment: this really saved my time, i have had backbone refered before underscore ..thanks

Comment: @Deeptechtons: You could tell the view what the search term is and the view could bind the `"reset"` on the collection; then when rendering, the view could do the filtering based on the search term (if any). Then the `fetch` would trigger `"reset"` which would trigger a `render` and the render would deal with the filtering and everything should happen in the right order. The view would just need a little bit of logic (as usual) to deal with an empty collection.

Comment: @muistooshort Hi thanks for the tip. In this fiddle http://jsbin.com/exeyid/4/edit instead of searching through collection I trigger a event on collection. So will the event be triggered after collection is fetched or before ?

Comment: @Deeptechtons: Probably depends how long the `fetch` takes, you have to be prepared for those things to happen in any order.

Comment: @muistooshort How does one unset more than one attribute. Multiple unset calls ? `model.unset("foo");model.unset("bar");` is there a elegant syntax to this