# failed to load backbone in Ruby project

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

i'm trying to migrating my code from the design project (html / jquery only) to my ruby project, however, the Backbone library is failing to initialize with this error (picture attached): 'cannot call method 'extend' of undefine.

does anyone have any idea for this issue?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Backbone.Model.extend() is not a function", what have I done wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508420/backbone-model-extend-is-not-a-function-what-have-i-done-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, you must load them in the right order in the Ruby file.