# Backbone.js doesn't recognize a variable

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to use `Backbone.js` in a web page.

When I link to the `.js` file for `version 0.9.9` I get the following error at **line 225**.

```
 TypeError _ is undefined
 _.extend(Backbone,Events);
```

However, `_` is defined at **line 40**

```
  var _ = root._;
```

And that variable declaration isn't inside a loop or conditional statement.

Why doesn't line 225 recognize what line 40 declared?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Backbone.Model.extend() is not a function", what have I done wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508420/backbone-model-extend-is-not-a-function-what-have-i-done-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) is dependent on [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

Comment: And I am too dependent on idiocy.js